# How do Laravel route/controller parameters work?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-6

I understand that if I have a route of say api/users/{id} then this will get passed to the controller function as an $id param.

However if I have a api route of:

```
Route::patch('roadmap/{roadmapcourse}', 'RoadmapCourseController@update');
```

and a controller method:

```
/**
   * Update the specified resource in storage.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \App\RoadmapCourse $roadmapcourse
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
   */
  public function update(Request $request, RoadmapCourse $roadmapcourse)
  {
    $data = $request->validate([
      'user_id' => 'required|integer',
      'course_id' => 'required|integer',
      'stage' => 'required|integer',
      'title' => 'required|string',
      'creator' => 'required|string',
      'url' => 'required|string',
      'hours' => 'required',
      'completed' => 'required|boolean'
    ]);

    $roadmapcourse->update($data);

    return response($roadmapcourse, 200);
  }
```

Then I send a request to http://*projectname*/api/roadmap/2 - then 2 gets passed through as the param to the update function doesn't it?

But by the looks of the update function its expecting an instance of RoadmapCourse and not a single digit i.e. '2'?

Does Laravel, behind the scenes, search for a database entry for a RoadmapCourse with the id of 2, and then bring that in to the function as $roadmapcourse?

That's the only thing I can think of, and I can't find any documentation explaining what's going on.

P.S I also can't find any documentation regarding the variable naming convention of Class $variable i.e. RoadmapCourse $roadmapcourse, I understand what it does, just can't find any docs.

P.P.S I also can't find any documentation explaining the "docblocks" above a controller method e.g.

```
/**
   * Update the specified resource in storage.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \App\RoadmapCourse $roadmapcourse
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
   */
```

And what these '@param' declarations are actually for??

Any help or links to docs would be appreciated (I've been looking at the Laravel docs but can't find any mention or any of these things - hence posting on here)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know Laravel under the hood well enough to know the full reasoning but in your example, you're essentially instantiating `$roadmapcourse` as a `RoadmapCourse` object. If you simply had `Request $request, $roadmapcourse` you would be able to access `$roadmapcourse` as a standard variable which would be whatever you put in the URL, in this case 2

Comment: Thanks Andy. Yeah i understand that. In this case I was actually trying to access the object with an id of 2 and the code was working - I just didn't understand why it was working and what was going on behind the scenes. "Route Model Binding" was the answer.

Comment: Ahhh, yeah I've not actually looked into that yet. I think I will following on from this. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Laravel, behind the scenes, search for a database entry for a `RoadmapCourse` with the id of `2`, and then bring that in to the function as `$roadmapcourse`?

Yes, indeed it does. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding for more information.

> Since the `$user` variable is type-hinted as the `App\User` Eloquent model and the variable name matches the `{user}` URI segment, **Laravel will automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the corresponding value from the request URI.** If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP response will automatically be generated.

As for the other questions (note, try to limit questions to a single, concise question in the future), the variable name doesn't matter; `$roadmapcourse` could be anything, as long as the injected Model is correct. If you don't use `RoadmapCourse`, it'll try to find whatever model you pass, based on the primary key (generally `id`).

For the `docblocks`, that's standard function commenting. `@param` and `@return` can be parsed and display those values in a REST API document, but by default, they don't do anything aside from provide a visual reference. You can safely ignore those if you want.

Comment: Thanks Tim, yeah i thought about not posting 3 questions at once but I thought whoever answered may know the answer to all 3!

Comment: No worries! They're all pretty well interconnected in this situation, so not a big deal :) But just something to be aware of; might not be received well in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that if I have a route of say api/users/{id} then this
>   will get passed to the controller function as an $id param.

This is because the param will be stored a regular variable.

> However if I have a api route of (...) and my controller looks like this:
>
> ```
> public function update(Request $request, RoadmapCourse $roadmapcourse) { /** ... */ }
> ```
>
> It doesn't work.

This is because you are trying to use [Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) but, given your variable name (and route param) Laravel isn't able to resolve the proper class.

If you do this instead:

```
Route::patch('roadmap/{roadmapcourse}', 'RoadmapCourseController@update');
```

```
public function update(Request $request, $roadmapcourse)
{ //                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    dd($roadmapcourse); // you'll get the value
}
```

Of course, you can tell laravel to properly resolve your path variable to get a record from your database. To do so, you'll need to config a [Explicit Binding](http://public%20function%20boot()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20parent::boot();%20%20%20%20%20%20Route::model('user',%20App%5CUser::class);%20%7D). From the docs:

> #### Explicit Binding
>
> To register an explicit binding, use the router's `model` method to
>   specify the class for a given parameter. You should define your
>   explicit model bindings in the `boot` method of the
>   `RouteServiceProvider` class:
>
> ```
> public function boot()
> {
>     parent::boot();
>
>     Route::model('user', App\User::class);
> }
> ```
>
> Next, define a route that contains a {user} parameter:
>
> ```
> Route::get('profile/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
>     //
> });
> ```

So in your case, try this:

```
# app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('roadmapcourse', App\RoadmapCourse::class);
}
```

Just then, Laravel will be able to resolve your route param:

```
Route::patch('roadmap/{roadmapcourse}', 'RoadmapCourseController@update');
```